# excel graphs via VB script on powerpoint presentation

Tags: vb.net

I have 16 graphs on a sheet named as Graphs and I would like this to be copied on 8 different slides. I have tried using the VB scripts available but it gives me an error where it says "path".  i dont know VB and i am struggling with it. Can somebody please help me.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far, so someone can spot the issue.

Comment: Can you just get a screen shot and copy the image?

Comment: Sub ExcelToPres()
Dim PPT As Object
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="D:\Data\MBR\Environment Availability_October- 2013_Version 1.1"
copy_chart "sheet_name", 2  ' Name of the sheet to copy graph and slide number the graph is to be pasted in
PPT.Save
PPT.Close
End Sub


Public Function copy_chart(sheet, slide)


Dim PPApp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object